# Spring-data query dynamoDB findById and another field

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, amazon-dynamodb

I am using Spring-data repository for dynamoDB.
I am trying to query the DB using my ID and another field like below:

```
public interface DataRepository extends CrudRepository<Image, ImageId> {

    List<Image> findByIdAndOrgId(ImageId imageId, String orgId);

}
```

Here my ID is imageId. Where this imageId contains hashKey and sortKey.

When trying to start the application, I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You have defined query method in the repository but you don't have any query lookup strategy defined. The infrastructure apparently does not support query methods!
```

Do not understand what should be done in this case. Could not find much issues when googled on this error. Is it that, I should not use ID in combination with another field? Should I give the hashKey and sortKey explicitly?

Edit 1:
findById (ImageId imageId) is working for me.

And for the above example, the orgId parameter is a GSI

Comment: Which version of spring-data you are using?

Comment: I am using Spring-data-dynamodb-5.0.4

Comment: From the trail and error methods I have done, I do not this the above scenario is valid in dynamoDB.
Reason behind is, DynamoDb takes hashkey and rangekey to query for the record. But here the orgId belongs to separate GSI. So dynamoDB is not able to query such record. Let me know if I am wrong.